# Grindelwald to Jungfraujoch by car

Tags: europe, switzerland, swiss, swiss-citizens, jungfrau-region

We will be staying near Grindelwald's train station with a car. We want to go to Jungfraujoch. We were thinking of buying this package which includes a ticket from grindelwald train station to jungfraujoch + cable car for around 140 euros for adults and free for kids.

https://www.getyourguide.co.uk/interlaken-l793/interlaken-to-jungfraujoch-by-train-to-the-top-of-europe-t186585/

Do you think it might be better or cheaper if we go to Jungfraujoch or uptill a certain point with our car and then buy the train tickets from there? If so, until which point can we go with our car (somewhere parking is also available)?

Comment: Hike or bike to *Kleine Scheidegg* may be a cheaper solution (possibly healthier but for sure not a easy one).

Answer (score 8):

Ticket for the Jungfraujoch you best buy from the railway itself. Do not get an third party involved. Especially one that makes incorrect claims like "likely to sell out". You should never buy a ticket for a mountain excursions till you know the weather, and in that area that means not more than 24 hours in advance.

The best thing to do in your case is to leave your car at your accommodation (or even better, not bring your car to Switzerland at all) and just walk or take the bus or train to Grindelwald Terminal, where the Eiger Express cable car brings you to the Eigergletscher station and from there by train to the Jungfraujoch. Ticket prices you can see at [www.jungfrau.ch](http://www.jungfrau.ch).

This ticket is only free for children if you have a Swiss Travel pass. The "getyourguid" website does not make this clear, setting you up for an expensive surprise...

You car will probably spend the entirety of your stay in the area parked, as all the interesting excursions are not car accessible.

Comment: this is very helpful! On a side note, is it safe to travel from Lucerne to Grindelwald and from Grindelwald to Interlaken/Zurich via car only? or is that also not possible?

Comment: @x89 yes, it's safe to travel by car even mid-winter. It's only 1000m above sea level ...

Answer (score 6):

You cannot drive to the Jungfraujoch.  The closest train station to the Jungfraujoch that has parking facilities is Grindelwald Grund.

Comment: Besides the imposibility to drive higher, when I considered going up, many years ago, the train tickets for most of the distance were cheap, it was the last bit which made it expensive, so even hiking up a few more stops will not safe costs.